# Не срабатывает точка остановки программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, отладка

При отладке столкнулся с такой проблемой-не срабатывает точка остановки программы. Выдает ошибку

> в настоящий момент попадание в точку, остановка не произойдёт. Нет загруженных символов для этого документа.

проблема возникает только с `Debug`, c `Release` все хорошо.

С чем это связано и как можно это исправить?

Comment: Можете показать код? И показать на нём где пытаетесь поставить точку? какие горячие клавиши нажимаете для отладки? и можно даже прикрепить скриншот с ошибкой (помимо уже указанной цитаты)

Comment: Бывает, что в конце рабочего дня пытаешься отлаживаться в конфигурации Release вместо Debug - это одна из возможных причин :)

Comment: А что за модуль? Может, вы используете не ту библиотеку, или не стоите её из исходников, а подключаете скомпилированную?

Comment: Обработчик MouseDown ImageBox'а. Но точки не срабатывают в любом месте. Сторонних библиотек не подключаю

Comment: А другие события мыша у ImageBox'а есть реакция?

Comment: Есть, но точки не работают

Comment: @Seedorf точки не работают, если для ваших dll/exe нет на диске соответствющих pdb-ов, или они есть, но не загружены студией. Посмотрите в окне debug/windows/modules состояние Symbol Status для того exe/dll, что пытаетесь отладить

Comment: Посмотрел-"загрузка символов пропущена"

Comment: вероятно Вам нужно вот эта https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc667410.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На будущее - может пригодится. У меня, судя по всему, не совпадали версии `.NetFramework` в отлаживаемом проекте-библиотеке и в дополнительно подключенном к нему. Поэтому я не мог провалиться на отладку в этот дополнительный проект-библиотеку.

Сначала отладка проваливалась в дополнительный проект-библиотеку, но потом что-то случилось и настал капут. Я и заново подключал этот дополнительный проект, и чистил папку `Debug`, и искал какие-либо настойки отладчика, и сравнивал файлы `.csproj` на предмет существенных различий, и колупался в главном `.sln` - никакого эффекта.

Потом в свойствах проекта в разделе "Приложение" я поставил одинаковые версии `.NetFramework` и точки останова заработали.

Answer (score 0):

была аналогичная проблема, не работала точка останова (писало ошибка C4715)  проблема оказалась в том что после создания проекта я переименовал корневую папку. после того как скопировал все содержимое и проверил код в другом файле - точка останова заработала.

Answer (score 0):

У меня выводило такое же сообщение при поставке точки останова.

Оказалось, что при сборке у меня выдавало следующие сообщение (даже не смотря на то что оно компилировалось) :

```
1>cl : командная строка warning D9007: для "/Gm" требуется "/Zi или /ZI"; параметр пропущен
```

Поставил в свойствах проекта флаг `/ZI` - и точки останова заработали.

Answer (score 0):

Не нашёл ни где решения этой проблемы, которое помогло мне.

1. Удалить из директории проекта папки 'bin' и 'obj'.
2. В шапке visual studio при сборке проекта, сначала выбираете конфиг 'Debug' и собираете (ctrl + b), а затем 'Release' и снова сборочка (как на фото).
3. Так вот, **отладку надо делать именно в конфиге 'Debug'** (логично, но для меня это открытие, никогда не замечал ранее такого).
4. Регулярно пересобирайте все конфигурации, по мере развития проекта. Если этого не делать - придется делать п.1 (по крайней мере у меня так случилось).

[image: Тут меняется конфиг]